# Android application for remote access

Tags: android, remote-access

Is it possible for android to do the basic command eg. shutdown or restart via internet.. For example in internet cafe's. I wanted to shut down or restart the client computer in a cafe.

Comment: Unless your question is about programming, I suggest you move it to [android enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) sister site ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can install a VNC Server on the PC's and a [VNC client](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) on your android phone.

Using VNC you can pretty much do anything you want to remotely.

Comment: Can i used VNC in web based platform?

Answer (score 0):

I'am using [Unified Remote](http://www.unifiedremote.com/) for such things. It's fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I actually have an App on the Market that does this exact thing. All I did was have the user run a server on your computer, and then just use Sockets. Easy.

Comment: sir if i may.. would you mind to elaborate the process of how you create that app?..